# How to change the language of a UIAlertView to match the device language?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, localization, uialertview

My app has a localizable.strings file which supports English , French and German languages and I have an alert view that pops up when you tap a button so how can I make this alert view's language matches the language  that the device has been setup for ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As any other localized string in your app, make `UIAlertView` message,title, and button title localized in your Localizable.strings file.

See this example:

```
UIAlertView *alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Connection Error", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"Couldn't connect to the internet. Please check your network connection", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the devices locale settings for language.

```
NSString *localeLang = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

This will return the code for that language... you can find a list of which codes are used for which languages with this google search:

http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ISO+639-1+codes&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

It should be noted that some languages ****may**** have multiple codes, I have never checked so I don't know.

Comment: *after re-reading this question it occurred to me you said "localized strings" I don't know what these are so perhaps it does what I described above for you.... If so sorry but I will leave this answer up as a reference for anyone trying to do it manually.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use `NSLocalizedString()`!

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 2.0 see this example:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: (NSLocalizedString("alert_Title" , comment: "Alert title.") as String),
        message: "Your message here",
        preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
        title: (NSLocalizedString("alert_RateButton" , comment: "Alert button to rate in App Store.") as String),
        style: .Default,
        handler: { action in UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(
            string: "https://itunes.apple.com/your_app_at_app_store")!)
            print("Going to App at AppStore")
    }))

    // DISMISS
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
        title: (NSLocalizedString("alert_BackButton" , comment: "Alert back button.") as String),
        style: .Default,
        handler: nil))
    presentViewController(
        alert,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}
```

Enjoy.